# Any object isomorphic to an initial object in a category is initial

Tags: category-theory

I am in trouble with a detail of the proof I've found, in particular with the fact that the isomorphism is unique but this property does not seem necessary.

The proof goes as follow.

Suppose *I* is initial and that *I'* is isomorphic to it. Let's say *f* is an iso with *g* as its inverse:

[image]

Given any other object *X* we want to show that there is a morphism $I' \rightarrow X$ and we want to show that this arrow is unique, so *I'* is initial.

Now, since *I* is initial there is a unique morphism $I \rightarrow X$, say *s*, and so we have at least a morphism $I' \rightarrow X$, that is $s \circ g$. To show that there are no other possible arrows $I' \rightarrow X$ we pick any arrow $t: I' \rightarrow X$ and we notice that:

$$
s = t \circ f \tag*{both arrows $I \rightarrow X$, $s$ is unique}
$$
$$
s \circ g = t \circ f \circ g \tag*{precomposition of g} 
$$
$$
s \circ g = t \tag*{$f \circ g = id$} 
$$

So any arrow $t: I' \rightarrow X$ is exactly like $s \circ g$, and that concludes the proof.

What bothers me is the fact that the proof does not use the uniqueness of the isomorphism between $I$ and $I'$. We've just proven that given any isomorphism $f: I \rightarrow I'$, $g: I' \rightarrow I$, any arrow $t: I' \rightarrow X$ is the same the unique arrow that goes from $I$ to $X$ precomposed with $g$. But we need that the iso $f, g$ is unique to have well behaviour: let's say there is another iso $f',g'$ between $I$ and $I'$, $t$ would be equal to two different things, $s \circ g$ and $s \circ g'$, because the same reasoning would apply.

That is just not possible, because $I$ is initial so the iso $f,g$ is unique, so it feels like this fact should be exploited, but the book says: "we did not need to use the fact that $I$ and $I'$ are uniquely isomorphic as that uniqueness follows from $I$ being initial".

I am confused.

Comment: Please tell me  the statement of  proposition of this proof you are confused about.

Comment: @Nakayama I've already reported it at the end of the question :)

Comment: That statement is pretty straightforward. If we are saying that $f:I\to I'$ is an isomorphism and $I$ is initial then it is understood that $f$ is unique. There is no need to state it further. It is not clear what your confusion is.

Comment: @JohnDouma I am with you, but my confusion derives from the statement of the book that I've mentioned. It says that the fact that `f` is unique has not been used...yes we can derive it, but it seems that it is needed to properly show the uniqueness of t

Comment: If there is an iso $f:X\to X'$, then, for any object $Y$, $Hom(X,Y)\cong Hom(X',Y)$. So a hom-set is the singleton iff the other one is (i.e. $X$ is initial iff $X'$ is); the uniqueness of the isomorphism $f$ is not involved (but follows easily if $X$ and/or $X'$ are initial)

Comment: @JerryScott yes in your proof the uniqueness is not involved, but the one I've presented shows that $\forall t. t = s \circ g$, and that is true, but it ignores the fact that $s \circ g$ is unique, so it seems incomplete. $s$ itself is unique, but without the fact that $s \circ g$ is unique in turn (and it is, just not taken into consideration) something feels missing to me.

Comment: You want to prove that $sg=t$. Since $f$ is an iso,  $sgf=tf$ implies $sg=t$. Again, this holds for a generic isomorphism $f$, its uniqueness  is not important. (If it's not clear $sgf=tf$ just because their domain is an initial object)

Comment: @JerryScott that holds for a generic isomorphism, you are able to show that $sg = t$ for each possible iso $f,g$...and that is a problem if you have distinct isos $f,g$ and $f', g'$ because you can show $sg = t$ and $sg' = t$ so $g = g'$, so those isos must be the same or you have a contradiction...so uniqueness is important

Comment: Yes @JerryScott we are implicitly deriving/exploiting the fact that the isomorphism is unique, because two of them would be the same, so things behave correctly, we cannot simply throw away this fact as if it were unimportant

Comment: The point is that, if you have an initial object $I$ and an iso $f:I\to I'$, in order to prove that $I'$ is initial, you use that $I$ is initial  and that $f$ is an iso. The uniqueness of $f$ follows ("separately") by the fact that $I$ initial

Comment: Thus your problem: "if there are two different isos $f,f'$ with inverses $g,g'$, I could obtain two distinct $sg,sg'$ from an arrow $s:I\to X$" does not sussist, as there are no distinct isos $g,g':I'\to I$ assuming that $I$ is initial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that in order to highlight why the uniqueness of the isomorphism is not necessary, it's valuable to prove the analogous statement for [coproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coproduct).

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are objects of some category, and suppose we have some isomorphism $f:X\sqcup Y\to Z$ from a choice of coproduct $X\sqcup Y$ to another object $Z$.
Then, $Z$ is also a coproduct of $X$ and $Y$!

Of course, the above statement is imprecise: a coproduct is not just an object, but an object equipped with some additional structure.
More precisely, the coproduct $X\sqcup Y$ comes with canonical maps $i_X:X\to X\sqcup Y$ and $i_Y:Y\to X\sqcup Y$.
So, in order to say that $Z$ is also a coproduct, I need to provide similar structure (that is, maps $j_X:X\to Z$ and $j_Y:Y\to Z$).

To do so, we just follow our nose: define $j_X$ to be the composite $X\xrightarrow{i_X}X\sqcup Y\xrightarrow fZ$, and define $j_Y$ similarly.
Now, we just need to prove that $(Z, j_X, j_Y)$ satisfies the universal property of a coproduct of $X$ and $Y$.

So, suppose we have an object $W$ with maps $k_X:X\to W$ and $k_Y:Y\to W$.
Then, we need to show that there exists a unique map $k:Z\to W$ such that the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>j_X>> Z @<j_Y<< Y \\
@VVV @V\exists!kVV @VVV \\
@>>k_X> W @<<k_Y<
\end{CD}
commutes (that is, $k_X=k\circ j_X$ and $k_Y=k\circ j_Y$).

To prove this, we need to piggyback off the fact that $X\sqcup Y$ is a coproduct, and we have an isomorphism $f:X\sqcup Y\to Z$.
Indeed, we get from the universal property of $X\sqcup Y$ a unique map $u:X\sqcup Y\to W$ such that $k_X=u\circ i_X$ and $k_Y=u\circ i_Y$, so we can construct the morphism $k:Z\to W$ as the composite $Z\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}X\sqcup Y\xrightarrow uW$.
Indeed, we see that $k\circ j_X = (u\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ i_X) = u\circ i_X = k_X$ and similarly for $Y$.

Conversely, if we have a map $k':Z\to W$ such that $k'\circ j_X=k_X$ and $k'\circ j_Y=k_Y$, then the map $k'\circ f:X\sqcup Y\to W$ must coincide with the universal map $u:X\sqcup Y\to W$ (by uniqueness of $u$), meaning $k'\circ f=u$ or in other words $k'=u\circ f^{-1} = k$.
This proves the uniqueness of $k$.

Let me summarise all of this work:

**Proposition.** Let $X\sqcup Y$ be some coproduct of $X$ and $Y$, and let $f:X\sqcup Y\to Z$ be *any* isomorphism. Then, $Z$ can be made into a coproduct of $X$ and $Y$.

In particular, $f$ is no longer necessarily unique as an isomorphism in the category.
Instead, the statement is different: once you *give* $Z$ the structure of a coproduct in the way described above, only then is $f:X\sqcup Y\to Z$ the unique isomorphism that is compatible with the coproduct structure.
(In fact, there is a correspondence between coproduct structures on $Z$ and isomorphisms $X\sqcup Y\to Z$.)

You may notice that the proof of the proposition for coproducts is very similar to the proof for the initial object provided in your question. This is because they are both instances of a more general proof for arbitrary [colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimit) (anything isomorphic to a colimit can be made into a colimit).

This is why the proof for the fact that any object isomorphic to an initial object is initial does not require the uniqueness of the isomorphism. It just *happens* to be unique by the universal property of initial objects, as described in the comments!

Comment: Maybe I was focusing on the wrong side of the equation. Given *any* isomorphism $f,g$ between $I$ and $I'$ we firstly prove that for any other object $X$ there is a morphism $I' \rightarrow X$ that is $s \circ g$, then with the $t$ argument we prove that $s \circ g$ is equal to any other arrow $I' \rightarrow X$ so $s \circ g$ must be unique as well so $I'$ is initial.

Comment: Then because  is monic then , the inverse of the iso, must be unique so any iso , between ,′ is unique so there is just one.

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct: any object equipped with any isomorphism to an initial object is initial. *Therefore*, the given isomorphism was unique. It is not necessary to assume that the isomorphism was unique beforehand.